# Why does my CSS not take effect on page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a React application with a component containing a chart. The chart is implemented correctly, but I am having a weird behavior with the CSS.

I have the following css in my code meant to center a chart on it's section of the page:

```
.chart-container {
border: 1px solid #000000;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 20px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
/* display: inline-flex; */}
```

Applied as such to a chart component using the react-style css:

```
<div className={styles["chart-container"]}>
    <BudgetPlot />
</div>
```

When I reload the page, my chart appears squished to the left side of its container like so:
[image: squished chart]

From this screen, if I navigate to my css code referenced above, comment it out, then uncomment it, the chart appears as the css intends for it to be displayed:
[image: chart as expected]

There is more code to the project, but only this css seems to be having an issue.

Can anyone help me to understand what is going on? I'd like to be able to resolve this, but I dont know where to start. Let me know if I can provide more information!

Comment: Most likely something does not load in time and calculates width bad. Try inspecting elements to see what properties set for chart

Comment: I have an identical application in another React project with identical CSS and a different chart with more data that is working fine